# Remove numbers from string sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large database in which I want to do a part string search. The user will enter characters: `JoeBloggs.`

For arguments sake if I had a name `Joe 23 Blo Ggs 4` in the database. I want to remove everything in the name other than A-Z.

I have the `REPLACE(Name, ' ','')` function to remove spaces and the `UPPER()` function to capitalize the name.

Is there a more efficient fast way maybe by terms of regex to replace anything other than A-Z. I cannot change the values in the database.

Comment: You say you can't change the data. Can you add a computed column to the existing table? Or add a new table with a foreign key and your computed value?

Comment: @Laurence - Yea I suppose I can do this but can we do this in a temporary table in a stored procedure? If not then I can request this computed column, all i need is the function to do the replace. Thanks for your prompt response

Comment: I'd not recommend using regexps if performance matters. The way you use is obvious but still a good one!

Comment: @DmitryVyakhirev - There could be some rouge characters like ' " @ /, it is a messy database so will I need to do multiple REPLACES to get rid of every instance of a bad character

Answer (score 52):

1st option -

You can nest `REPLACE()` functions up to 32 levels deep. It runs fast.

```
REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (@str, '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '')
```

2nd option -- 
do the reverse of -

[Removing nonnumerical data out of a number + SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630472/removing-nonnumerical-data-out-of-a-number-sql)

3rd option - if you want to use regex

then
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=27205

Answer (score 24):

This one works for me

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @NumRange as varchar(50) = '%[0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

and you can use it like so

```
SELECT dbo.[RemoveNumericCharacters](Name) FROM TARGET_TABLE
```

Answer (score 7):

Try below for your query. where val is your string or column name.

```
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', REVERSE(val)) > 1
                THEN LEFT(val, LEN(val) - PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', REVERSE(val)) + 1)
            ELSE '' END
```

Comment: I've replaced `ELSE '' END` with `ELSE val END` so it also returns when no numbers are in it.

Comment: works great for stripping any trailing nonalphanumeric characters.

Comment: it doesn't work if the string has numbers leading or in the string.

Answer (score 7):

I just started relearning SQL...and I read this somewhere:

```sql
SELECT TRIM('0123456789' FROM customername )
```

You can also use this to remove spaces or other symbols as well. Just include it in the first parameter within the quotes `''`.

Comment: Almost! It's: `SELECT TRIM('0123456789') FROM customername`

Comment: Note that this only removes the characters from the start and end, but not the middle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

Quoting part of @Jatin answer with some modifications,

use this in your `where` statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM .... etc.
        Where 
         REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE
        (REPLACE (Name, '0', ''),
        '1', ''),
        '2', ''),
        '3', ''),
        '4', ''),
        '5', ''),
        '6', ''),
        '7', ''),
        '8', ''),
        '9', '') = P_SEARCH_KEY
```

Answer (score 2):

One more approach using Recursive CTE..

```
declare @string varchar(100)
set @string ='te165st1230004616161616'

;With cte
as
(
select @string as string,0  as n
union all
select cast(replace(string,n,'') as varchar(100)),n+1
from cte
where n<9
)
select top 1 string from cte
order by n desc


**Output:**   
  test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DecLARE @input varchar(50)= 'Joe 23 Blo Ggs 4'
    SELECT TRANSLATE(@input,'0123456789','          ') As output1,
            REPLACE
            (
                TRANSLATE(@input,'0123456789','          ') /*10 spaces here*/
                , ' '
                ,''
            ) as output2
```

Comment: we can use the TRANSLATE function. State the list of chars to be removed as a continous array and then with what they have to be removed with

Comment: This is a good one. It is equivalent of using multiple nested REPLACE functions on a string. You can also use TRIM to remove leading and trailing spaces for output2.
ie., TRIM(TRANSLATE(@input,'0123456789','          ')) as output2

Answer (score 1):

Entire SELECT returns string: `$P@M  from Python`. Multiple spaces can be removed using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql).

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE
    (
        TRANSLATE
        (
            '$P@M 1244 from93 Python', -- Replace each char from this string
            '123456789',               -- that is met in this set with
            '000000000'                -- the corresponding char from this set.
        ), 
        '0',  -- Now replace all '0'
        ''    -- with nothing (void) (delete it).
    ) AS CLEARED;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but I'm sure people are still hitting this page. You can do this easily nowadays with:

```
 REPLACE(TRANSLATE(YourField, '1234567890', '##########'),'#','')
```

TRANSLATE turns the numbers into '#'. REPLACE removes the '#'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything after first digit (was adequate for my use case):

```
LEFT(field,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',field+'0')-1)
```

Remove trailing digits:

```
LEFT(field,len(field)+1-PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',reverse('0'+field))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PATINDEX not like ^ alpha numeric - 0-9A-Za-z, keep looping while there are non alpha numeric characters in your string. Within the loop search for the non alpha numeric characters one at a time using the same PATINDEX logic. Once the non alpha numeric character is located inside each loop iteration, use the built in STUFF function to replace your unwanted character with an empty string.
Return cleaned string value from your function once outside the WHILE loop.

Create FUNCTION dbo.RemoveNonAlphaNum (@strin VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN

declare @disposeChar int

WHILE (PATINDEX('%[^ 0-9A-Za-z]%', @strin) > 0)

BEGIN

SELECT @disposeChar = PATINDEX('%[^ 0-9A-Za-z]%', @strin)

SET @strin = STUFF(@strin, @disposeChar, 1, '')

END

```
RETURN @strin
```

END

```
Remove the a-z if you want to remove only numeric

Sample usage
```

select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaNum('600/7015/8&&££---)))')

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

## One-line solution with easy editability

You can do it with `REPLACE` + `TRANSLATE`, like so:

```sql
DECLARE @CharsToReplace VARCHAR(256);
SET @CharsToReplace = '0123456789' -- Set the characters you want to strip here. Whitespace must be in the middle of the string, otherwise TRANSLATE will ignore it.

SELECT DISTINCT
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(my_column, @CharsToReplace, REPLICATE('~', LEN(@CharsToReplace))), '~', '') AS cleaned_up
FROM my_table;
```

This approach has the advantage that it's very easy to change the replacement character list later. You simply edit `@CharsToReplace`.
There no need to add or remove additional calls to `REPLACE` or change the code to tweak the functionality.

### How it works

#### TL;DR

We remove the characters with two passes.
We first use `TRANSLATE` to replace all the unwanted characters with '~'.
We then use `REPLACE` to replace all instances of `~` with an empty string, which produces the cleaned-up result string.

#### Details

`TRANSLATE` is effectively find-and-replace. It takes three strings:

1. The input
2. A list of characters that should be matched
3. A list of characters they should be replaced with.

Because the mapping of characters is one-to-one, **2** and **3** must be the same length.

It our case, **1** is the input, and **2** is `@CharsToReplace`.
We generate **3** by using `REPLICATE('~', LEN(@CharsToReplace))`, which generates a string of '~' with the exact same length as `@CharsToReplace`.

Suppose our column value is 'ABC123'.
When we execute the entire statement:

```sql
TRANSLATE('ABC123', @CharsToReplace, REPLICATE('~', LEN(@CharsToReplace)))
```

We first evaluate `REPLICATE`, giving us:

```
TRANSLATE('ABC123', @CharsToReplace, '~~~~~~~~~~'))
```

Every character from `@CharsToReplace` is then replaced with a `~` from the generated string.

This gives us the result `ABC~~~`.

Finally, we use `REPLACE` to strip every `~` character from the string, which is effectively:

```sql
REPLACE('ABC~~~', '~', '')
```

And we're left with the cleaned up result: `ABC`.

Of course, if your string values must be able to contain `~`, you can use a different character as the replacement placeholder.

That's all folks!

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but you can do something like this:

```
Create Function dbo.AlphasOnly(@s as varchar(max)) Returns varchar(max) As
Begin
  Declare @Pos int = 1
  Declare @Ret varchar(max) = null
  If @s Is Not Null
  Begin
    Set @Ret = ''
    While @Pos <= Len(@s)
    Begin
      If SubString(@s, @Pos, 1) Like '[A-Za-z]'
      Begin
        Set @Ret = @Ret + SubString(@s, @Pos, 1)
      End
      Set @Pos = @Pos + 1
    End
  End
  Return @Ret
End
```

The key is to use this as a computed column and index it. It doesn't really matter how fast you make this function if the database has to execute it against every row in your large table every time you run the query.

Comment: very slow solution, fast is required

Comment: If you insist on doing `Select name from test where dbo.AlphasOnly(name) = 'JoeBloggs'` then this will be slow even if the function takes 0 time. You still pay the cost of reading all the rows off the disk (assuming when you say large table you mean your database doesn't fit in memory). To make it fast you need to find a way of indexing it, which is why I suggest a computed column.