# How to extract in between string

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to grab if something like this

ID 1234 20/2/2014 0:0:0 UK AUS 4/8/2014 12:20:0

only want to grab UK AUS

the date time always change

Comment: Possible Duplicate

[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)