# Extract uppercase letters and numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to process a string so that only uppercase letters and digits are taken. Trying to use PATINDEX because I want to keep this concise - it will be part of a bigger query.

There are quite a few examples out there showing something similar, however I seem to be missing something. So far I've got

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100)

SET @string = 'AbcDef12-Ghi'

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9]%',@string) <> 0
    SET @string = STUFF(@string,PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9]%',@string),1,'')

SELECT @string
```

As per e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server), however this doesn't seem to be doing what I need.

Using `[^0-9]` outputs `12`, which is correct.

However `[^A-Z]` outputs `AbcDefGhi`, i.e. both uppercase and lowercase. Doesn't matter if I use `[^A-Z]` or `[^a-z]`, both return all letters.

I think I may be missing something simple? I found a few suggestions referring to collation and tried to use COLLATE with PATINDEX as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) but couldn't get it to work.

Note: I'm doing this as a one-off query on a SQL Server database to find some data - this will not be reused anywhere else so things like performance, SQL injection (mentioned quite frequently in this context) etc. are not a concern.

Comment: Maybe you could use tally table + substring for 1 character and compare that to allowed characters? Something similar that DelimitedSplit8k uses http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: @Blam thanks - I did more research on this. JamesZ, the solution below works for me plus I'm not registered at SQL Server Central.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using [`COLLATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) and the a case sensitive collation such as `Latin1_General_BIN`:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100)

SET @string = 'AbcDef12-Ghi'

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9]%',@string COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @string = STUFF(
        @string,
        PATINDEX('%[^A-Z0-9]%',@string COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN),1,''
    )
END

SELECT @string
```

This will output:

> AD12G

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works! Weird, I remember trying this exactly with Latin1_General_BIN yesterday but maybe it only works if it's not 5pm :P

Comment: The logic in general is clear and sound, but I would use a variable to store the result of PATINDEX to avoid calling the function twice at every iteration.

Comment: @AndriyM You are correct and I would normally do that, but OP stated in the question that this is a one-off and performance is not an issue.