# Remove numbers found in string column

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, replace, regexp-replace

What would be the SQL to remove all numbers found in an otherwise string column using Sqlite (an Oracle example would be appreciated too)?

Example : I would like to remove all numbers from entries like this :

`291 HELP,1456 CALL`

Expected output:

`HELP,CALL`

edit: I have edited the question because it is not only from one entry that I want to remove numbers but many of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you do it in the language, you embedded sqlite, or you use this SQLite code, that removes all numbers:

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '0', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '1', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '2', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '3', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '4', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '5', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '6', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '7', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '8', '' );
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '9', '' );
```

Comment: Some other ways of achieving this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Using **TRANSLATE** and **REPLACE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '291 HELP' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '1456 CALL' str FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT REPLACE(translate(str, '0123456789', ' '), ' ', NULL) str
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

STR
---------
HELP
CALL

SQL>
```

Using **REGEXP_REPLACE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '291 HELP' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '1456 CALL' str FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT trim(regexp_replace(str, '[0-9]+')) str
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

STR
---------
HELP
CALL

SQL>
```

**POSIX character class**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '291 HELP' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '1456 CALL' str FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT trim(regexp_replace(str, '^[[:digit:]]+')) str
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

STR
---------
HELP
CALL

SQL>
```

**Perl-extensions**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '291 HELP' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '1456 CALL' str FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT trim(regexp_replace(str, '\d+')) str
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

STR
---------
HELP
CALL

SQL>
```

Comment: ERROR: function regexp_replace(text, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @Luffydude That's not an Oracle error, any Oracle error starts with `ORA-` error code followed by error message. Post your use case with the Oracle version and explain what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
select '''' || regexp_replace('123 help 321', '\d+') || '''' from dual;
```

Comment: It will always have a space on both sides, you need to trim the spaces.