# sql query to sum data based on criteria

Tags: sql, sum

I have my table data sums as follows

```
---------------------
Building   | Area m2
---------------------
|Dante 12  |   10
|Dante 10  |    5
|Dante 9   |    2
|Crandley  |   20
|Bence     |   30
```

I want to sum Building Area but buildings like '%dante%' I want to combine into sum "Dante" like below:

```
-------------------
Building | Area m2
-------------------
Dante    |  17
Crandley |  20
Bence    |  30
```

Comment: What version of SQL you are using, as an exact answer may depend on this.

Comment: I assume that you don't want to fix this just for "Dante", and that you can actually have more combination of numbers, i.e: "Crandley 8"?

Answer (score 2):

Group by with case will do the trick for sample data given,`like` of this type can use index as well

```
Select 
case when building like 'dante%' then 'Dante' else building end,
sum([area m2])
from
table
group by 
case when building like 'dante%' then 'Dante' else building end
```

if there are numbers for other columns,you can strip out the numbers first and do the rest of stuff like below

```
;with cte
as
(select REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (building, '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '') as bulding,aream2
 from #temp
)
select building,sum(aream2)
from
cte 
group by 
building
```

**References:**
[Remove numbers found in string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656220/remove-numbers-found-in-string-column)

Comment: thank you very much! it is correct answer, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Works only if numeric value is to be removed**

Numeric value is to be replaced (Nested replace function can go upto 32 level deep) and group by column.

```
SELECT x.Building, SUM(x.AreaM2) AS [Area m2]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE (Building, '0', '')
        ,'1', '')
        ,'2', '')
        ,'3', '')
        ,'4', '')
        ,'5', '')
        ,'6', '')
        ,'7', '')
        ,'8', '')
        ,'9', '') [Building], AreaM2 FROM Buildings) AS x
GROUP BY x.Building
```