# Remove digits from string which is ending by digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of `Emails`. In that column there are email addresses which end with some digits. I want to remove those trailing digits.

Example:

```
jjj@yahoo.com234
lhf@hotmail.com1984
lll@gmail.com567
```

Result:

```
jjj@yahoo.com
lhf@hotmail.com
lll@gmail.com
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what have you tried, what doesn't work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server

Comment: @user2983359 wht happening with current answers ??

Comment: The result which I mention in my question is what I'm expecting.

Comment: so, wht is issue in current answers ?

Comment: just use the query update dbo.Email set  Email = REPLACE(Email, SUBSTRING(Email, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', Email), LEN(Email)), '')

Comment: with your this query it removes all digits wherever he founds in the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove numbers from string sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server)

Comment: @user2983359 yes it will remove digits wherever it founds, & your question is to be like that.

Comment: @user2983359 pls. check my updated answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: @user2983359 have you checked the Manoj Pilania answer before accepting the solution?

Comment: because of it removes all numbers from your email address not just ending digits.

Comment: yes I have checked and apparently it does the same thing. Your script leave empty fields and his script put NULL in the empty fields

Comment: Bt u want only end digits to be removed right?

Comment: yes you are right I want end digits to be removed

Comment: @ManojPilania function removes all digists from your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution, I used this many times.

Create a function from given code.

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveSpecialChars] (@s VARCHAR(2000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
     WITH SCHEMABINDING
  BEGIN
     IF @s IS NULL
        RETURN NULL
     DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(256)
     SET @s2 = ''
     DECLARE @l INT
     SET @l = LEN(@s)
     DECLARE @p int
     SET @p = 1
     WHILE @p <= @l BEGIN
        DECLARE @c INT
        SET @c = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1))
        IF @c BETWEEN 65 AND 90 OR @c BETWEEN 97 AND 122 OR @c = 64 OR @c = 46
           SET @s2 = @s2 + CHAR(@c)
        SET @p = @p + 1
        END
     IF LEN(@s2) = 0
        RETURN NULL
     RETURN @s2
  END
```

Then you can use this function given below query

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[Email]
    SET Email = AA.Email    
    FROM [dbo].[Email] AEL
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 [dbo].[RemoveSpecialChars](Email)AS Email FROM [dbo].[Email] at WHERE at.Email=AEL.Email) AA
```

Comment: When I run your function
I get this error message
Invalid object name 'dbo.RemoveSpecialChars'.

Comment: yes your script is also working. But my question now is.. what is the difference between your scripts and between of @Yogesh Sharma?

Comment: I just write the function to remove numbers, this function can be reused. Yogesh is using string function, I am using ASCII code to check that the character is number or not

Comment: have you checked the solution which you have given ?

Comment: it removes all numeric values rather than ending digits of email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Check below :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(32)

SET @DATA = 'jjj1@yahoo.com234'

SELECT REPLACE(@DATA, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('@', @DATA) + 1, LEN(@DATA)), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('@', @DATA) + 1, LEN(@DATA))), LEN(SUBSTRING(@DATA, CHARINDEX('@', @DATA) + 1, LEN(@DATA)))), '') AS DATA

+================+
| DATA           |
+================+
| jjj1@yahoo.com |
+----------------+
```

Update query :

```
UPDATE dbo.Email
  SET
      Email = REPLACE(Email, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1, LEN(Email)), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1, LEN(Email))), LEN(SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1, LEN(Email)))), '');
```

Comment: your query just shows me the result but does not update my table.

Comment: show your actual query from which you would like to update the email.

Comment: If an email address contains numeric chars, like "myadress44@gmail.com" this script not working.

Comment: i have given the answer according, the question.

Comment: yes you updated answer is working :). Thank you very much @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: @YogeshSharma If the domain name has any number like yahoo11.com your script doesn't work but I guess this is not necessary for the answer.

Comment: So, now wht is the issue with current updated answer ??