# Trimming any Leading or trailing characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table where I have some raw data. My requirement is to trim any leading or trailing spaces and operator characters in the given string column. Examples of operator characters include `+ - . > < = : ;"`

Examples:

Value `+Payment`  should be trimmed to `Payment`
Value `->300 Write` should be trimmed to `300 Write`

Comment: Is your list of operator characters exhaustive (or do you have an exhaustive list)? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Trim minus signs? Seems a bit odd. "-12 degrees" -> "12 degrees".

Comment: @Larnu I'm using SQL Server 2014. Yes. the list is exhaustive (+, -, ., >, <, =, :, ;,",)

Comment: @jarlh raises a good point. Think we might need a slightly larger scope here, or this could be an "xy problem".

Comment: @jarlh Agreed. But its a requirement.

Comment: check this answer it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071850/6606630

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('+Payment'),('->300 Write'),('-:<Test,:%');

SELECT SUBSTRING(YourString,A.posFirst,A.posLast-A.posFirst+2)
FROM @tbl 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%',YourString) AS posFirst
                  ,LEN(YourString)-PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%',REVERSE(YourString)) AS posLast) AS A
```

The result

```
Payment
300 Write
Test
```

You can add any allowed character to the pattern...

Comment: Looks promising. Testing it out.

Comment: What is you basis for tagging SQL 2014?  I see nothing from the user.

Comment: I just plain missed that.  I up voted you a while ago.

Comment: @Paparazzi No problem ;-) Btw: You are right, that your answer is helpful in a way, at least it informed be about this promising new feature :-D Still it's more a comment than an answer though. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try with PATINDEX

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       Val = '+Payment'
    UNION
    SELECT
       ' 300 Write'
)
SELECT
    *,
    NewVal = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Val,PATINDEX('%[A-Z0-9]%',Val),LEN(Val))))
    FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

What version are you on.  Trim will do characters on 2017 version.

[Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql)

> TRIM ( [ characters FROM ] string )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18808411)

Comment: @cjm How is this not an answer?  It is a function that does exactly what the OP is asking.  When I answered the version was not tagged.  This answer could be valuable to user with 2017 or later.