# Removing leading and trailing commas

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to find a way to remove trailing and leading commas in the SELECT statement. Here is some sample data:

[image: Sample]

```sql
SELECT
    GRAIN, MATERIAL, BACKING, GRITS,
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(PROPERTIES, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',') PROPERTIES,
    SPECIAL, APPLICATION, PRODUCTTYPE
FROM PRODUCTFINDER
```

I tried using trim, rtrim, and ltrim but none of them changed the strings.. Idk if I was using the wrong syntax or what, but could someone help me please?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your select statement so we aren't guessing what you are doing?

Comment: And if possible, it would be better to prevent these junk characters getting stored in the first place

Comment: just added the select statement @SeanLange

Comment: ltrim and rtrim remove leading and trailing spaces. Those functions don't remove commas. Could you share some more details? It would be really helpful to see your table and data. Here is a great example of what to post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ But it looks like the real problem is the data.

Comment: @SeanLange i have a picture with the table and data as a link in the question but i can't embed it because i'm not high enough rep

Comment: Pictures are not good. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I would probably put this data into multiple tables (4 exactly) a header and 3 detail tables. For your issue... I would use a string splitter and get rid of the nulls. This would remove the interior nulls though.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838676/sql-server-trim-character/14647204#14647204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option.

This is a non-destructive approach that will eliminate any number of repeating `commas`  and forces a final cleanup via the double pipes

For the expansion,reduction, and elimination I picked two obscure characters `†‡`

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) =',,,,Some,,,,,Content,,,'

Select
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace('||,' + @S + ',||', ',', '†‡'), 
                    '‡†', ''
                ),
                '†‡', ','
            ),
            '||,', ''
        ),
        ',||', ''
    )
```

**Returns**

```
Some,Content
```

> **EDIT - Removed the LTRIM()/RTRIM()**

Comment: @kodym Happy to help.

Comment: neat approach too, though confusing at first +1

Comment: @scsimon Full Disclosure:  Gordon demonstrated this technique several months ago use <>  ,  I just use more obsure characters to avoid conficts with HTML

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
    GRAIN, MATERIAL, BACKING, GRITS,
    TRIM(',' FROM PRODUCTFINDER.PROPERTIES) AS PROPERTIES,
    TRIM(',' FROM PRODUCTFINDER.SPECIAL) AS SPECIAL,
    TRIM(',' FROM PRODUCTFINDER.APPLICATION) AS APPLICATION,
    TRIM(',' FROM PRODUCTFINDER.PRODUCTTYPE) AS PRODUCTTYPE
FROM PRODUCTFINDER
```

I am not sure which columns you want to trim.

This variant of [TRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is available since SQL-Server 2017.

---

If you have an earlier version of SQL-Server, do this in the Font-End (VB). This also gives you the possibility to replace multiple commas by single ones in the middle of the text.

```
Dim s = ",,,Abc,,,Def,Xyz,,,"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, ",{2,}", ",").Trim(","c))
```

Prints

> Abc,Def,Xyz

`Regex.Replace(s, ",{2,}", ",")` uses the a regular expression `,{2,}` to find 2 or more occurrences of commas and replaces them by one single comma. `.Trim(","c)` removes leading and trailing commas.

For `Regex` you need a

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

---

Another variant uses string split with the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option and then joins the parts again to form the result.

```
Dim s = ",,,Abc,,,Def,Xyz,,,"
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", parts))
```

Comment: This breaks the select statement, i have SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method using `PATINDEX` with `LEFT` and `RIGHT`.

```
declare @var varchar(64)= ',,,,,,,,asdf,dsf,sdfsd,asdf,,,,,,,,'

select 
    left(right(@var,len(@var) - patindex('%[^,]%',@var) + 1)
        ,len(right(@var,len(@var) - patindex('%[^,]%',@var) + 1)) - patindex('%[^,]%',reverse(right(@var,len(@var) - patindex('%[^,]%',@var) + 1))) + 1)
```

Just change `@var` to your column name.

This code strips the leading commas by searching for the first value that isn't a comma, via `patindex('%[^,]%',@var)` and takes everything to the `RIGHT` of this character. Then, we do the same thing using `LEFT` to remove the trailing commas.

```
select 
   Special =  left(right(Special,len(Special) - patindex('%[^,]%',Special) + 1),len(right(Special,len(Special) - patindex('%[^,]%',Special) + 1)) - patindex('%[^,]%',reverse(right(Special,len(Special) - patindex('%[^,]%',Special) + 1))) + 1)
   ,[Application] = left(right([Application],len([Application]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[Application]) + 1),len(right([Application],len([Application]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[Application]) + 1)) - patindex('%[^,]%',reverse(right([Application],len([Application]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[Application]) + 1))) + 1)
   ,[ProductType] = left(right([ProductType],len([ProductType]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[ProductType]) + 1),len(right([ProductType],len([ProductType]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[ProductType]) + 1)) - patindex('%[^,]%',reverse(right([ProductType],len([ProductType]) - patindex('%[^,]%',[ProductType]) + 1))) + 1)
FROM PRODUCTFINDER
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is not ideal place for manipulating strings so *trim logic* should be at programming level

As far as trimming particular character is required in query, refer to below thread

[Trimming any Leading or trailing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765403/trimming-any-leading-or-trailing-characters)