# SQL Wildcard within data

Tags: sql, wildcard

My situation is a bit odd. I have generated filenames inserted into a database that are to be matched with downloaded files later, however the downloaded files contain a random ID in the middle of their name.

If I include the wildcard characters on the generated filename that's inserted into the database, is there anyway to compare that against the actual downloaded file?

Generated name example: `just-a-file-name-and-a-suffix.mp4`
Actual downloaded file: `just-a-file-name-51935-and-a-suffix.mp4`

I have zero way to actually know what those 5 digits will be. I only know that there will be 5 digits. Ideally I'd insert the generated name into the database something like `just-a-file-name-%-and-a-suffix.mp4` and use the `LIKE` keyword in a SQL query but it doesn't work that way.

Is there anything I can do to solve this and get a match?

Comment: Please tag your database

Comment: Are those 5 digits separated by `-`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring, replace and some other functions if you like.
Following is an example of using replace and creating a function for it.

`
CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

```
Declare @NumRange as varchar(50) = '%[0-9]%'
While PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
```

End
and you can use it like so

SELECT dbo.RemoveNumericCharacters FROM TARGET_TABLE
`
taken from following post -- [Remove numbers from string sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server)

Note you be passing on your file string to the function and it will return the file name without the numbers in it.

Thanks