# Function to separate letters and numbers in strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have strings in **str** column

| ID | STR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AB1234KK |
| 2 | ABC123DEF |
| 3 | 1234AB |

I need to separate the letters and numbers on each record and place them on a new row.
I tried using the STRING_SPLIT function which allows me to put a delimiter between letters and numbers and split them. But I don't know how.

I am expecting a result like this

| ID | STR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AB |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 1 | KK |
| 2 | ABC |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | DEF |
| 3 | 1234 |
| 3 | AB |

Comment: Though you *could* do this in T-SQL, I'm don't think it's the *right* language to do it,

Comment: What's the actual problem? What do the real data look like? What you ask isn't string splitting, it's pattern matching and SQL Server doesn't have regular expression functions.  There are JSON and XML values that could help if the text already is in such a form, or can easily be converted with replacements. It's a lot easier to clean up the data before inserting it into the database

Comment: It looks like you want to group _consecutive runs_ of letters/digits and create output rows with the separated groups. Is that the case? Does the order of the result rows matter? Your sample results provide no way to determine that particular order.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably better to do with Python. But there is a trick I learned from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server) which can be applied here. First, translate the characters (or digit) to blank, and then, split

```
; with cte as (
select a.*
from (values 
('1', 'AB1234KK'),
('2', 'ABC123DEF'),
('3', '1234AB')
) a (Id, string )
)
select cte.Id
, b.val
from cte
  cross apply (
    select value val from string_split(TRANSLATE(cte.string, '0123456789', REPLICATE(' ', 10)), ' ')
  ) b
where b.val <> ''

union all
select cte.Id
, b.val
from cte
  cross apply (
    select value val from string_split(TRANSLATE(cte.string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', REPLICATE(' ', 26)), ' ')
  ) b
where b.val <> ''
order by id, val
```

Comment: That's very neat, a small suggestion is to change the long space string into a `REPLICATE(' ', 28)` or however long the strings are

Comment: @siggemannen I made the change as you suggested

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in the comments, T-SQL is really not the ideal language for this, but that being said, you *can* do it. The method I use here is to create a row for each character in the value, using `GENERATE_SERIES` and `SUBSTRING` and then work out what "group" they are in using the "old" `ROW_NUMBER` method. Then I can aggregate the individual characters using `STRING_AGG` in their individual groups. This results in a solution like below:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.Str,
           GS.value,
           SS.C,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.ID ORDER BY GS.value) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.ID, CASE WHEN SS.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1
                                                      WHEN SS.C LIKE '[A-z]' THEN 2
                                                 END ORDER BY GS.value) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,'AB1234KK'),
                (2,'ABC123DEF'),
                (3,'1234AB'))V(ID,Str)
         CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1,LEN(Str))GS
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.[Str],GS.[value],1)))SS(C))
SELECT G.ID,
       STRING_AGG(G.C,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS NewStr
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.ID,
         G.Grp
ORDER BY G.ID,
         G.Grp;
```

If you have any other characters that aren't alphanumerical, then these would be implicitly split into a 3rd group.

This, however, will only work in SQL Server 2022+. If you are on 2019+ then you'll need to replace the `GENERATE_SERIES` function with your own tally function. If you aren't on SQL Server 2017+ then you'll also need to replace `STRING_AGG` with the old `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) solution (you'll be able to find solutions for both of these with the use of your favourite search engine). With no version tagged here, I assume you are using 2022, as that is the latest version at the time of writing.

---

For completion, here is a 2016- friendly version. If you are more recent versions, adjust appropriately:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@LastNumber bigint, @Zero bit) 
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @Zero = 0
        AND @LastNumber IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@LastNumber,0))
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7) --Up to 10,000,000 rows
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally T;
GO
SELECT V.ID,
       V.Str
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,'AB1234KK'),
            (2,'ABC123DEF'),
            (3,'1234AB'))V(ID,Str);
GO
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.Str,
           T.I,
           SS.C,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID ORDER BY T.I) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID, CASE WHEN SS.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1
                                                       WHEN SS.C LIKE '[A-z]' THEN 2
                                                 END ORDER BY T.I) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY fn.Tally(LEN(Str),1) T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(YT.[Str],T.I,1)))SS(C))

SELECT G.ID,
       (SELECT '' + SA.C
        FROM Grps SA
        WHERE SA.ID = G.ID
          AND SA.Grp = G.Grp
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)') AS NewStr
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.ID,
         G.Grp;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

A fully portable solution - except for the string aggregation function, which varies between the bigger DBMS players: SQL Server's `STRING_AGG()` function.

1. get a list of integers, from 1 to 10.
2. verticalise the the strings, one letter per row, using that list of integers, and `SUBSTRING()`
3. "sessionise" the vertical data in two steps: an OLAP counter set to 1 if previous was digit and current is alpha, or vice versa, followed by a running sum of that OLAP counter.
4. aggregate by `ID` and the obtained session id, and use `STRING_AGG()`

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                         
indata(ID,STR) AS (
-- your input, don't use in final query
          SELECT 1,'AB1234KK'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'ABC123DEF'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'1234AB'
)
-- end of input; real query starts here
-- replace following comma with "WITH"
,
i(i) AS (
            SELECT   1
  UNION ALL SELECT   2
  UNION ALL SELECT   3
  UNION ALL SELECT   4
  UNION ALL SELECT   5
  UNION ALL SELECT   6
  UNION ALL SELECT   7
  UNION ALL SELECT   8
  UNION ALL SELECT   9
  UNION ALL SELECT  10
)
,
vertical AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , i
  , SUBSTRING(str,i,1) AS letter
  , CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTRING(str,i,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS is_digit
  FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
  WHERE SUBSTRING(str,i,1) IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTRING(str,i,1) <> ''
)
,
w_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE
      WHEN is_digit <> LAG(is_digit) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY i)
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM vertical
)
,
w_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY i)  AS session
  FROM w_counter
)
SELECT
  id
, session
-- , LISTAGG(letter USING PARAMETERS separator='') AS wrd
, STRING_AGG(letter,'') AS wrd
FROM w_session
GROUP BY id,session
ORDER BY id,session
```

| id | session | wrd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | AB |
| 1 | 1 | 1234 |
| 1 | 2 | KK |
| 2 | 0 | ABC |
| 2 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 2 | DEF |
| 3 | 0 | 1234 |
| 3 | 1 | AB |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t9eZj3lV)